# Virtualisation, SSE4 not active on Core2Quad 9550 (Yorkfield)

Tags: cpu

I have a [Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q9550](http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLAWQ) installed and it is supposed to feature SSE4 and virtualisation instructions ( cpu flags vmx and sse4_1 ), but CPU-Z reports it does not:

[image: CPU]

The mainboard is a [Gigabyte EP35-DS4](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2744).

[image: Mainboard]

I've tried both Windows, Linux 32-bit and 64-bit kernels and the flags are missing in all accounts.

On the other hand, another Q9550 works fine, although on another mainboard model - still Gigabyte.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flashing the MB did make it work. Although the CPU was listed as supported and functioned properly, virtualisation was not available for it in the revision I had installed.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would go into the BIOS and make sure that the Virtualisation bit / VT is set to enabled as it is disabled by default on some motherboards.

As for SSE4, I again would look in the BIOS, but I have never had to deal with this before and have never seen an option to have it disabled.

Comment: Whether these options are available or not is determined not only by the CPU, but also by the motherboard. If these options are not visible in the BIOS, and if you have the latest version of the BIOS, then they are simply not available for your model.

Comment: @harrymc - I ended up flashing the MB and now it works. Mind putting your comment in an answer so I can accept it?